# HTML5 canvas paint optimize paint without lags

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My problem then i painting longer than 20seconds begin lagging. i think because it's have a lot of points into array. How i can optimize it? Drawing lines must be smooth like in example, but i have lags :/

```js
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    
  }
  
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.clearPath();
  
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: I drew on your example for 1 minute and did not experience any lagging. Is there more code involved? What device are you testing on?

Comment: Do you try painting about one minute without release mouse ?

Comment: Today i tested with different browser and did not any lagging. On ubuntu 14.04 with mozilla firefox lagging but with other systems and other browsers did not any lag. I think problem not in code but in my browser.